# How to create multiple databases based on client's request in node.js and postgresql?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

Can I create multiple databases with the same structure in node.js and postgresql?
Can I do this with Prisma?

The project must create a new database with a pre-built structure when a new user is registered.

I haven't tried it yet. I just want to know if this is possible.